# Insert variables into a SQL Server table in stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2014, sql-server-2016

I am trying to insert variables into SQL Server table dynamically inside a stored procedure but I'm not able to accomplish it because of the syntax. Can someone correct me what am I doing wrong in the below code. Thanks.

Code I have tried:

```
SET @SQLStmt1 = N'INSERT INTO TestTable (TableName) 
                  VALUES(' + @ResulTableName + N')'
EXEC sp_executesql @SQLStmt1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are close, but you should use a parameter for the value:

```
SET @SQLStmt1 = N'INSERT INTO TestTable( TableName ) 
                              VALUES(@ResulTableName)';

EXEC sp_executesql @SQLStmt1, N'@ResultTableName NVARCHAR(MAX)', 
                   @ResulTableName = @ResulTableName;
```

If you printed out `@SQLStmt1`, you would see that the single quotes are not correct.

Comment: How to do this if I have more than one column in the table?

Comment: You just add additional parameters for the columns.

Answer (score -1):

you can do it by adding triple quotes ''' 
this will resolve your problem

```
SET @SQLStmt1 = N'INSERT INTO TestTable( TableName ) 
                              VALUES(''' + @ResulTableName + ''')'
EXEC sp_executesql @SQLStmt1
```

the reason behind that is that triple quote in the dynamic SQL will become a single quote when the code get executed.

Comment: This is a bad practice, particularly unnecessary when using `sp_executesql` which accepts parameters.